# Converting Gradle Tomcat configuration to Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, gradle

I'm trying to do the Spring REST tutorial, and I've downloaded the sources and run the whole project successfully. However, it runs on a Gradle script but I'd like to use Maven. I've added all the dependencies to my pom.xml, and the Maven Tomcat plugin, but when I run `mvm tomcat:run-war` everything goes well, except nothing is served to `localhost` and in the results from the command I get the line `[INFO] Skipping non-war project.

The gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'tomcat'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'propdeps'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-maven'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-idea'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "http://download.java.net/maven/2"
    }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:0.9.8'
    classpath 'org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.1'
  }
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    def tomcatVersion = '7.0.42'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}"
    tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}") {
      exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', module: 'ecj'
    }

    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.8.1'

    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.5'
    runtime 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.2'
    runtime 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.2'
    runtime 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.9'

    provided 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'

    testCompile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:0.8.1'
    testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.3.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5"

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.6'
}

tomcatRunWar.contextPath = ''
```

The pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>tut-rest-3-complete</groupId>
  <artifactId>tut-rest-3-complete</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/mkyongWebApp</path>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.42</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.42</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.42</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to tell Maven to package the project as a WAR. Add `<packaging>war</packaging>`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>tut-rest-3-complete</groupId>
  <artifactId>tut-rest-3-complete</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
   ...
```